# Cuantas palabras coinciden en un texto python

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy intentando resolver el siguiente problema con la manipulación de ficheros:

Hay tres archivos de texto:

- archivo1.txt
  `Esto es un documento de prueba`
- archivo2.txt
  `Este es el segundo documento de prueba`
- archivo3.txt
  `No hay nada`

En todos hay un pequeño texto.

El script que quiero hacer, quiero que por cada fichero lo abra, lo lea y me indique si las palabras que quiero están o no. Si hay más de dos coincidencias el archivoX se queda, si es menor que borre el archivo:

```
import os

archivos = os.listdir(".\\textos")

# Palabra que quiero que se busquen en cada uno de los archivos
palabras = ['es','casa','segundo']
si = "SI"
no = "NO"

# Posible contador para llevar la cuenta de los sies
c = 0
# Por cada archivo, que me los abra y me los lea
for file in archivos:
    leer_archivos = open(".\\textos\\"+ file, 'r').read()
    # Por cada palabra en el array palabras
    for palabra in palabras:
        # Comprobar si la palabra esta o no
        if palabra in leer_archivos:
            print(file,"La palabra", palabra+" "+si)
            # Si esta sumar 1
            c += 1
        else:
            print(file,"La palabra", palabra+" "+no)
    if c>1:
        print("En ",file, "hay mas de una coincidencia")
    else:
        print("En ",file, "NO hay mas de una coincidencia")
```

La salida del script es esta

```
archivo1.txt La palabra es SI
archivo1.txt La palabra casa NO
archivo1.txt La palabra segundo NO
En  archivo1.txt NO hay mas de una coincidencia
archivo2.txt La palabra es SI
archivo2.txt La palabra casa NO
archivo2.txt La palabra segundo SI
En  archivo2.txt hay mas de una coincidencia
archivo3.txt La palabra es NO
archivo3.txt La palabra casa NO
archivo3.txt La palabra segundo NO
En  archivo3.txt hay mas de una coincidencia
```

Como se puede apreciar en el archivo 3 no hay ninguna coincidencia y aún así me dice que hay más de una coincidencia cuando no lo hay.
Como en el archivo3 no hay ninguna coincidencia me gustaria borrar el archivo con os.remove() pero hasta que no me valide correctamente no puedo hacerlo.

Espero que alguien pueda ayudarme, creo que el probrema es el contador pero no se me ocurre nada...

Gracias!!

Comment: Tienes que poner  `c=0` dentro del bucle  `for file in archivos`, para que el contador vuelva a cero en cada fichero. Tal como está, en cada nuevo fichero que abres el contador sigue con el valor que le puso el fichero anterior.

Comment: Cierto!! Muchas gracias!!! No me puedo creer que fuera eso... No sabía que mas hacer porque no veía porque el bucle no me funcionaba